# Add tag taxonomy to wp_query search for wordpress custom post types

Tags: php, ajax, taxonomy, wordpress

I have a wordpress ajax search field that is querying 2 custom post types, product and tutorials. I want to be able to add tags to the post types and have the field results based on those tag searched.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_custom-search', 'search_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom-search', 'search_ajax');
function search_ajax() {
  if($_GET['s'] === '') {
    wp_send_json(array(
      'results' => [],
    ));
  }
  else {
    $query = new WP_Query( array('s' => $_GET['s'], 'post_type' => array('product', 'tutorial'), 'tag' => '') );
    wp_send_json(array('results' => array_map(function($p){
      return array('title'=>get_the_title($p),'uri'=>get_permalink($p),'category'=>get_the_category($p->ID, 'search_category'),'postType'=>get_post_type($p),'thumb'=>get_the_post_thumbnail($p->ID,'medium'));
    }, $query->posts)));
  }   
}
```

Comment: Did you see this https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters ? According to it, you should be able to query by tags quite easily

Comment: It only shows examples if you're looking for specific tag or multiple tags. I want  query and search all tags.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want the returned posts to have all their tags shown, or do you just need a query to pull all tags from product and tutorial posts?

Comment: Basically if the user searches the word blue any post tagged blue will be displayed. Not trying to show the tags at all, just the posts. its a contextuall search

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand you :D 

If you want to search by keyword OR tag, this seems to be the solution: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-search-results-from-either-contenttitles-or-tags?replies=5#post-2575541

Or you can just have 2 queries: one search by keyword, the other by tag, and merge the results

If you want to search only by tag, remove this part from the array 's' => $_GET['s'] , and use this 'tag' => '$_GET['s']

Comment: Right now it searches keywords from the title and content I'm guessing. I want to add the tags to the search also. The tags get queried and the results are the associated post. Tags are not displayed at all. I'm sure the solution is something simple. I just cant manage to query ALL tags and the keywords.

Comment: Ok, to query title, content and tags, you have 2 options: first, to use the link I pasted in the comment above. The other way would be to introduce another query with parameters: array('post_type' => array('product', 'tutorial'), 'tag' => $_GET['s']) , and then merge the results with your existing query

Comment: Yup Merging them worked great. thx